# Adding Multiple Sidebars

Tags: sidebar, register-sidebar

Hello all I would like to add multiple sidebars to my wordpress site I currently have 2 sidebars registered in functions.php like so:

```
function themename_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'themename' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => 'Sidebar for all pages',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );

register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebartwo', 'themename' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => 'Sidebar for product page',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );



}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'themename_widgets_init' );
```

in my sidebar.php I currently have this code which will add default data to my sidebars incase I have not added any widgets.

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>

            <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </aside>

            <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'themename' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'themename' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_register(); ?>
                    <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                    <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
```

Would anyone know how to go about doing the same for my sidebar-2 from what I have read i must create a sidebar-2.php which I have done and included the same code as above like so:

```
            <aside id="search" class="widget widget_search">
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </aside>

            <aside id="archives" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Archives', 'themename' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly' ) ); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <aside id="meta" class="widget">
                <h1 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'themename' ); ?></h1>
                <ul>
                    <?php wp_register(); ?>
                    <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
                    <?php wp_meta(); ?>
                </ul>
            </aside>

        <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
```

But unfortunately it is not working does anyone know why?

Comment: when you say it's not working, can you be more specific? are you seeing sidebar-1's content in both places, or nothing at all for sidebar-2? can you show the code from your theme template that is calling `get_sidebar()`?

Comment: @karpstrucking I can see the widget areas in my dashboard and I can see the sidebar-1 showing up when I added the sidebar to my template page i use `<?php get_sidebar('sidebar-2'); ?>` the sidebar-1 still shows in its place.

Comment: if your file is named `sidebar-2.php` then the correct use is `get_sidebar( '2' );`

Comment: lol @karpstrucking thanks alot that was the problem I thought it went `<?php get_sidebar('ID'); ?>` but its already registered and waiting to be called with a sidebar template page of course thank you very much again

Comment: How would I mark this as resolved can you put your answer in an answer and not in a comment so you get the necc recognition. @karpstrucking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sidebar file is named `sidebar-1.php` the correct usage of the `get_sidebar()` ([WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar)) function would be:

```
<?php get_sidebar( '1' ); ?>
```